# Proof Checking a "Logic Equation" Puzzle

Tags: proof-verification, puzzle

Did a "logic equation" puzzle that took me several hours. Feel like it should have been faster, and that there surely is a more elegant path to the solution.

Sharing the proof to spot redundancies, omissions, faulty logic and areas to simplify. If there are best practices I should follow in terms of formatting and expression, that would also be a nice contribution.

You can try your hand at the puzzle [here](https://www.brainzilla.com/logic/logic-equations/6x6/11/) before you look at my proof, if you like.

> Given that all variables are unique integers, and given the following
>   statements:
>
> $B \ne 1; B \ne 2; B \ne 5$
>
> $D \ne 4; D \ne 6$
>
> $D+E=C+F$
>
> $B+C=A+F$
>
> Find the value of all variables.
>
> $$ \begin{array}{c|lcr} & \text{1} & \text{2} & \text{3} & \text{4} &
>  \text{5} & \text{6} \\ \hline A & & & & & & \\ B & x & x & & & x & \\
>  C \\ D &  &  & & x &  & x\\ E \\ F \\ \end{array} $$

Proof:

Given that the sum of all variables (A-F) is 21 and that $B + C = A + F$,

- $21 - (D+E) = A + B + C + F$
- $D+E$ must produce an odd-numbered sum so that $21 - (D+3)$ produces an even-numbered difference.
- $D$ and $E$ must have opposite parity.

Given that the sum of all variables (A-F) is 21 and that $A+F \ne C+F$,

- A sum of 7 is impossible for $D+E$, $B+C$ or $A+F$ as it would create a paradox $(A+F=C+F)$

Given that $D+E = C+F$ and that $D$ and $E$ have opposite parity,

- $C$ and $F$ must have opposite parity.

Given that $D+E=C+F$ and $B+C=A+F$,

- Sums of 3, 10 and 11 are not possible for $D+E$, $C+F$ or $A+F$ because they cannot be produced two or more ways in this data-set.

Given that $(21-(D+E))/2=B+C$, that $D+E$ must be odd, that $D+E>4$, that $D+E \ne 7$, that $D \ne 4$ and that $D \ne 6$,

- $E \ne 1$
- If $D+E$ produced a sum equal to 5, both $B+C$ and $A+F$ would produce a sum of 8.
- If $D+E$ produced a sum equal to 9, both $B+C$ and $A+F$ would produce a sum of 6.

Testing the only eligible odd number for B (3) given that $B+C$ must produce a sum of 6 or 8, the only possible option for C would be 5. This leads to a paradox when entering values for $D+E=C+F$ ($5=7$).

Given that both $B+C$ and $A+F$ must both produce equal- and even-numbered sums; this signals common parity for B and C, and common parity for A and F.

Given that the remaining options for B are 4 and 6; this signals even parity for B and C, and odd parity for A and F.

As $B+C$ must equal 8 given that $B$ cannot be 1, 2, 3, or 5, $B=6$ and $C=2$.

Given that $C=2$ and that $C+F \ne 7$, $F=3$.

Given that $D+E=5$ and that $E \ne 1$, $D=1$ and $E=4$.

$A+3=8$, so $A=5$.

Result:

$$ \begin{array}{c|lcr} & \text{1} & \text{2} & \text{3} & \text{4} &
 \text{5} & \text{6} \\ \hline A & & & & & ✓ & \\ B & x & x & & & x & ✓ \\
 C & & ✓ \\ D & ✓ &  & & x &  & x\\ E & & & & ✓\\ F & & & ✓\\ \end{array} $$

Answer (score 1):

This goes a little faster:

Start is same as yours:

Since $B+C=A+F$, we have $B+C+A+F$ is even, and since $A$ through $F$ add up to $21$, $D+E$ must be odd

But we cannot have $D+E=7$, for then $B+C=A+F=7$, and also $C+F=7$, and so $A+F=C+F$ which is impossible.

OK, so far it's the same.

But at this point in your proof you note that $D+E$ cannot be $3$,$10$, or $11$ ... but note for same reason you state it also cannot be $4$ (that is: $D+E=C+F=4$ does not work)

So: $D+E$ is odd, greater than $4$, and smaller than $10$, but is not equal to $7$, so there are only two options left: $D+E=5$ or $D+E=9$

But the latter doesn't work, for then $D+E=C+F=9$, so $A+B=3$, and $B$ is neither $1$ or $2$

So, $D+E=C+F=5$ and $A+B=11$, and since $B$ is not $5$, we have $B=6$ and $A=5$

Since $B+C=A+F$ that means $F=C+1$, and since $D+E=C+F$ and since you only have numbers $1,2,3,4$ left, that means $F=3$ and $C=2$.

So $D$ and $E$ are $1$ and $4$, and since $D$ is not $4$, we have $D=1$ and $E=4$

Note that I never used the clue that $D$ is not $6$ ....